# old EDMX project using "iAnywhere.Data.SQLAnywhere" provider

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, sqlanywhere

I have an older project that was using

iAnywhere.Data.SQLAnywhere

SWATModel.edmx:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<edmx:Edmx Version="3.0" xmlns:edmx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edmx">
  <!-- EF Runtime content -->
  <edmx:Runtime>
    <!-- SSDL content -->
    <edmx:StorageModels>
    <Schema Namespace="SWATModel.Store" Alias="Self" Provider="iAnywhere.Data.SQLAnywhere" ProviderManifestToken="12" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm/ssdl">
        <EntityContainer Name="SWATModelStoreContainer">
```

and the connection in

web.config

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="SWAT" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.SWAT.csdl|res://*/Models.SWAT.ssdl|res://*/Models.SWAT.msl;provider=iAnywhere.Data.SQLAnywhere;provider connection string=&quot;userid=dba;password=PASSWORD;databasename=swat;servername=LAPTOP-0IMGM8KC;host=127.0.01&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
    <add name="SWATEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.SWATModel.csdl|res://*/Models.SWATModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.SWATModel.msl;provider=iAnywhere.Data.SQLAnywhere;provider connection string=&quot;userid=dba;password=PASSWORD;databasename=swat;servername=LAPTOP-0IMGM8KC;host=127.0.01&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

and I changed the 2 files to be

SWATModels.edmx:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<edmx:Edmx Version="3.0" xmlns:edmx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edmx">
  <!-- EF Runtime content -->
  <edmx:Runtime>
    <!-- SSDL content -->
    <edmx:StorageModels>
    <Schema Namespace="SWATModel.Store" Alias="Self" Provider="System.Data.SqlClient" ProviderManifestToken="2008" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm/ssdl">
        <EntityContainer Name="SWATModelStoreContainer">
```

and web.config

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-SWAT-20140409184116;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-SWAT-20140409184116.mdf"/>
    <add name="SWAT" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.SWAT.csdl|res://*/Models.SWAT.ssdl|res://*/Models.SWAT.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;userid=dba;password=PASWORD;databasename=swat;servername=LAPTOP-0IMGM8KC;host=127.0.01&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
    <add name="SWATEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.SWATModel.csdl|res://*/Models.SWATModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.SWATModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;userid=dba;password=PASWORD;databasename=swat;servername=LAPTOP-0IMGM8KC;host=127.0.01&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

I compile it and it seems to work but the database tables etc are not created, any suggestions?

Here is a littel more of the EDMX

I see it referes to a schemaGenerator

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<edmx:Edmx Version="2.0" xmlns:edmx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2008/10/edmx">
  <!-- EF Runtime content -->
  <edmx:Runtime>
    <!-- SSDL content -->
    <edmx:StorageModels>
    <Schema Namespace="SWATModel.Store" Alias="Self" Provider="System.Data.SqlClient" ProviderManifestToken="2008" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm/ssdl">
        <EntityContainer Name="SWATModelStoreContainer">
          <EntitySet Name="lkpBiome" EntityType="SWATModel.Store.lkpBiome" store:Type="Tables" Schema="DBA" xmlns:store="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/12/edm/EntityStoreSchemaGenerator" />
          <EntitySet Name="lkpClimateClassification" EntityType="SWATModel.Store.lkpClimateClassification" store:Type="Tables" Schema="DBA" xmlns:store="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/12/edm/EntityStoreSchemaGenerator" />
          <EntitySet Name="lkpCountry" EntityType="SWATModel.Store.lkpCountry" store:Type="Tables" Schema="DBA" xmlns:store="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/12/edm/EntityStoreSchemaGenerator" />
          <EntitySet Name="lkpRegion" EntityType="SWATModel.Store.lkpRegion" store:Type="Tables" Schema="DBA" xmlns:store="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/12/edm/EntityStoreSchemaGenerator" />
          <EntitySet Name="lkpSoil" EntityType="SWATModel.Store.lkpSoil" store:Type="Tables" Schema="DBA" xmlns:store="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/12/edm/EntityStoreSchemaGenerator" />
```

Comment: EDMX never creates database tables. It's *database-first*.

Comment: To switch from database-first to code-first copy out all of the entity definitions and and create a new code-first DbContext that has a `DbSet<T>` property for each one.  Then delete the .EDMX file from the project.  Then you can use Migrations to create a new database to store the entities.

Comment: Hey David i will research that , I added a bit more of the edmx it has EntityStoreSchemaGenerator which i thought was part of the codefirst set up. If you have any resorces that might help me i would appreciate them.

Comment: You can try `context.DataBase.Create()`, where `context` is an instance of your context.

Comment: That worked I, I delete the connection then recreated it then when opening the edmx designer it asked me to link them once that was done I just right clicked in the open canvas area of the EDMX designer and selected "create database from model". Then to go the otherway I added a column to a table then selected in the canvas update model from database and that new column was added in the model